# AWS config query with wildcard in resourceType

Tags: sql, amazon-ec2, aws-config

I'm trying to get all associated resource relationship types for a specific EC2.  Is it possible to use a wildcard in an AWS config query in the WHERE block with `resourceType` rather than having to declare each type?

What I am doing that's working:

```
SELECT
  *
WHERE
  resourceType IN (
    'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway',
    'AWS::EC2::NetworkACL',
    ...

  )
  AND relationships.resourceId = 'foo'
```

What I want to do, but it returns empty:

```
SELECT
  *
WHERE
  resourceType IN (
    'AWS::EC2::*'
  )
  AND relationships.resourceId = 'foo'
```

Have also tried but returns empty:

```
SELECT
  *
WHERE
  resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::*'
  AND relationships.resourceId = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard to use is '%'.

So your example will look like this:

```
SELECT
  *
WHERE
  resourceType LIKE 'AWS::EC2::%'
  AND relationships.resourceId = 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks any chance you got a link to the aws doc  for this syntax

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `AWS::EC2*`.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/target-multiple-resources-wildcard-configuration-aws-cloudformation-hooks/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).